# How to clear a timeout function inside a .hover() event?

Tags: jquery

The code below is basically what I want to do, which I understand is incorrect code.

So for a dropdown menu, I want to hide it with a delay. The problem is, when I hover onto another menu-item before the hide-delay is finished, it overrides the next `handlerIn`.

So is there a simple way to clear the `setTimeout` queue on the next `hover()`?

Again, the incorrect code below is just for explaining.

```
$('nav > ul > li').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(menuHide);
    $(this).find('ul').show();
}, function() {
    var menuHide = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
    }, 150);
});
```

UPDATE: Seems like `clearInterval()` is not what I'm looking for, because I still want to let it complete, instead of abort it.

Is there a `completeInterval()` by any chance? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your hover event has no reference to `menuHide` so it must be declared beforehand.

```
var menuHide;

$('nav > ul > li').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(menuHide);
    $(this).find('ul').show();
}, function() {
    menuHide = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
    }, 150);
});
```

**EDIT**

After some collaboration in the comments section, we determined that putting the code inside of the complete portion of the `animate` method was the way to go:

`.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

Comment: Ofcourse! But clearInterval is not what I'm looking for, I discovered. See my update. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you just take out the `clearTimeout(menuHide)` from the hover? I would imagine your timeouts would then run to completion.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But if I hover onto another menu-item before the `setTimeout()` is complete, it overrides code from the next `hoverIn` handler. This makes my dropdowns behave buggy.

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a full example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Also, is there a reason for using a setTimeout in this scenario vs using something like `animate`?

Comment: I am using `animate` to roll-down and roll-up the submenu, but after the animation has finished and hovering out, I want to `hide()` it. Therefor, the `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: Then why not put the code inside of the `complete` portion of the `animate` method - `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Darn, haven't even thought of that! Thanks for your time Chase! If you update your answer, I could check it, if you want.

Comment: Hope it helped! Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Make `menuHide` a global variable.

Comment: It does not need to be global (and it shouldn't be), just above this whole code block should do.

Comment: Agreed. In the context of the shown code, we can't tell the difference.